# MySQL: Limit the number of characters in LIKE clause?

Tags: mysql

I'm using this query in my autocomplete feature:

```
SELECT description FROM my_table WHERE LIKE "%keyword%"
```

But this query returns the entire content of the field which is sometimes too long.
Is it possible to limit the number of characters before and after "keyword" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show for example 5 characters before and after you word you can do it using `RIGHT`, `LEFT` and `SUBSTRING_INDEX`

```
select description, concat(RIGHT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(description, 'keyword', 1),5), 'keyword', LEFT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(description, 'keyword', -1),5) ) as snippet
from my_table
where description like "%keyword%";
```

Check it here : https://dbfiddle.uk/MZcVJgEL

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using MySQL's `REGEXP` operator here.  For example, to accept a maximum of 10 characters before and after keyword, you could use:

```sql
SELECT description
FROM my_table
WHERE col REGEXP '^.{0,10}keyword.{0,10}$';
```

Note that if you intend to match `keyword` as a standalone word, you may want to surround it by word boundaries in the regex pattern:

```sql
SELECT description
FROM my_table
WHERE col REGEXP '^.{0,10}\\bkeyword\\b.{0,10}$';
```

Comment: It doesn't work as the regexp clause limits also the found results. `REGEXP "^.{0,10}h.{0,10}$"` applied on a string such as "hello world!" wouldn't match as this string has more than 10 characters after the letter "h".

Comment: @Duddy67 In fact `'hello world'` does match this pattern, [as this demo shows](https://dbfiddle.uk/M_9JkHS4).

Comment: No it doesn't, you forgot the exclamation mark at the end `"hello world!"`

Comment: Then maybe what you want to do here is check the `LENGTH()` of the input?

Comment: No, I don't need `length()`. But @selVazi has suggested to use `concat()` combined with  `left()` `right()` and `substring_index()` which is an interesting idea. I think I'll try it out.